# Is this still WeakReference?

Tags: java, android, weak-references

I am creating a `WeakReference` and keeping it somewhere.

```
WeakReference<MySpecialObject> mWeakReference = new WeakReference<MySpecialObject>(new MySpecialObject("My","Special","Data"));
```

But some other external library(which I don't what it is doing it) really needs `MySpecialObject` instance. When I used something similar below:

```
ExternalLibraryThingy#useItWisely(mWeakReference.get());
```

*end of part #1*

after some time I do call

```
ExternalLibraryThingy#doSomethingUsefull(); //which I dont know it kept a reference while calling "useItWisely" method.
```

*end of part #2*

### Question

Until the end of part #1, is my in place created `MySpecialObject` object still weakly referenced? I mean if I call `mWeakReference.get()`, is there any chance of getting `null`? In other words can OS garbage collect it at will?

Until the end of part #2, if the `ExternalLibraryThingy` made and assignment while `useItWisely` and using that assigned value while `doSomethingUsefull`, can it throw a `NullPointerException`?

I guess one simple answer can be the answer for both of the question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed the dereferenced object to the `ExternalLibraryThingy#useItWisely` method. The external library does not care that you retrieved the object from a weak reference.

So whether the object has strong references in the external library depends entirely on the method that you called on it. Without knowing what the method does, it is impossible to know whether the object will still be referenced.

As for your second question, the library had the `MySpecialObject` reference directly. From the point of view of the external library, it is not going to be randomly replaced with `null`.

Comment: So assuming ExternalLibraryThingy kept a strong reference; as long as it keeps, `mWeakReference.get()` won't return null right?